# Excel vba - logic failure

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet(x4) that add up total hours worked by several employees. One employee's total comes to 24hrs. In my function, due to how Excel represents hours internally, that equates to 1. Based on the value of 'hours' it then formats the cell to show total hours:min for each person. I've checked - typename(hours)= double. I cannot see why hours>=1 doesn't equate to 'True' when hours = 1. If I add 1 minute to the spreadsheet values for that person, it works as expected?

```
Public Function format_hours(hours As Variant) As Variant   
If hours >= 1 Then
     format_hours = Application.Text(hours, "[hh]:mm")
ElseIf hours > 0 Then
     format_hours = Format(hours, "hh:mm")
Else
     format_hours = 0
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Using `Variant` is not recommended. You will benefit if you specify your variable types stronger. (Also, you are missing  an `f` in `format_hours` - Use `Option Explicit` to avoid such errors.)

Comment: I've just found that my variable 'hours' has a leading space. Removing it lets the logic work as expected. Where is that space coming from?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing how this function is being called. If you have specified your argument as a number instead of a variant, you would have caught this sooner.

Comment: Maybe your problem is that 24h = 1d+0h ?

Comment: Actually if this function is to be called from worksheet formulas, then Variants are sometimes recommended for the parameters, and sometimes for the return value, it's highly dependent on usage.  The `Option Explicit` I definitely agree with though.

Comment: Why not just use the `[hh]:mm` format for all numbers - and pass as `double` as others have mentioned?  If the time is less than 12 hours then it will still show as less than 12 hours, if more then it will work as well.

Comment: I'll try the [hh:mm] for all numbers but I did seem to have some difficulty with it when it exceeded 24hrs. The function is called from a cell when the workbook is calculated hence the use of 'variant'. The leading space I mentioned once removed allowed the function to return the correct time. I don't know where the leading space is coming from

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Hours as Variant` is *probably* coming through as a `String`, and not a Date/Double.  Since you never explicitly check/convert it to Date/Double then in your `If hours >= 1 Then` it's probably not doing the implicit conversions and comparision that you expect.

Solution: use explicit conversions and comparisons.  Implicit ones suck because they inevitably produce mysterious bugs like this.

Comment: Yes, checked it and it is coming through as dbl. Also tried casting it.